How to check which blocked is clicked in Spigot 1.21.4
So I'm just writing a plugin with Spigot 1.21.4 where I need to check if the player clicked on a Lectern. In the earlier version you could just do this:
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
    if (event.getClickedBlock() != null && event.getClickedBlock().getType() == Material.STONE) {
        // Actions to take here
    }
}

But in the newest version of Spigot this doesn't work since I can't import org.bukkit.Material anymore: Cannot resolve symbol "Material"
How can I do this check in the newest version?

I'm looking at the Spigot documentation for 1.21.4, and I don't see anything saying Material has been deprecated. Do you have a source showing the deprecation or any more information that can help provide context?

Im not sure if it got depricated but i cant import it. I tried it with version 1.18 where it worked just fine but as soon as I try it in version 1.21 i cant import in anymore

So i just figured out that you need to use a newer Intellij version. I used version 2023.1 and it didn't work there now I installed version 2024.3 and it works perfectly!
